# timer (for a countdown)

Tags: html

I created a countdown from 5 to 0. It start when you click on the "START" button:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<button id="start">START</button>
COUNTDOWN:<span id="countdown"></span>
  <script>
    let start = document.getElementById('start');
    let start_click = rxjs.fromEvent(start, 'click');
    start_click.subscribe(x => console.log('click'));

start_click.pipe(rxjs.operators.first()).subscribe(
  ()=> {
    let time = rxjs.timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      rxjs.operators.skip(0)
    , rxjs.operators.take(6)
    , rxjs.operators.map(x => 5-x)
      );

    time.subscribe(x => console.log('instant', x));
    let countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
    time.subscribe(x => countdown.innerText = x);
    start.disabled = true;

    let end = time.pipe(
    rxjs.operators.last()
    , rxjs.operators.repeatWhen(() => start_click)
    );

    end.subscribe(x=>start.disabled = false);
    start_click.subscribe(x => start.disabled = true);
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I struggle to find how to reset the countdown when the "START" button is pressed again.
I tried to add:

```
start_click.subscribe(x => countdown.innerText = 5);
```

But the value is static. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work after clicking 'Start' a second time is because you are using the [`first()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first) operator on your `start_click` observable.

This means the observable only emits on the first click, then completes.

Simply remove `.pipe(rxjs.operators.first())` and your code will work each time you click the button.

However, it's generally a good idea to avoid nested subscriptions when possible.  This can help you avoid memory leaks (*due not unsubscribing properly*) and make the code easier to understand.

You can avoid using nested subscriptions by using one of the "Higher Order Mapping Operators" [LINK](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/). This is just a fancy way of saying: operators that map the incoming value to another observable, subscribe to it, and emit those values. They also manage these "inner subscriptions" automatically.

The [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator will "switch" to a new observable whenever a new value is received. So in your case, whenever a new click is received, a new 5-second timer observable is created.

Simplified code could look something like this: [Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-single-subscription?file=index.html)

```
const start     = document.getElementById('start');
const countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');

const start_click = rxjs.fromEvent(start, 'click');

const time = start_click.pipe(
  tap(() => start.disabled = true),
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(x => 5-x),
    take(6),
    finalize(() => start.disabled = false)
  )),
);

time.subscribe(
  x => countdown.innerText = x
);
```

Notice how there is only a single subscription now.  We defined two different observables, `start_click` which is your stream of clicks and `time` which is your stream that emits the current value of the timer. `time` is defined from the `start_click` stream, so whenever a new click is received, under the hood a new timer gets created and emits values.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by `rxjs.operators.first()`,

try next

```js
start_click.pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(() => start.disabled = true)
    , switchMap(() => rxjs.timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        rxjs.operators.skip(0) // <- do you need it?
        , rxjs.operators.take(6)
        , rxjs.operators.map(x => 5-x)
        , rxjs.operators.finalize(() => start.disabled = false)
    )),
).subscribe(x => {
    console.log('instant', x);
    let countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdown.innerText = x;
});
```

Comment: Thanks you too, your answer helped me.